# Create moire pattern effect with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to take a clean image and make it look like it was a picture taken out of a screen.
Is there a way to do so with OpenCV or any other tool?

examples:
[moire example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpPea.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I'm new to image processing algorithms so nothing much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html) OpenCV function. By adding your image with a moirre pattern image like [this image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.szptcled.com%2Fnews-LED-Display.html&psig=AOvVaw272Htb7ZM1q2WX34KjZ1F6&ust=1619693037092000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCODB86njoPACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD). Here's how the way you add the image with the moirre pattern image:

```
img = cv2.imread("your_image.jpg")
mask = cv2.imread("mask_image.jpg")
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

alpha = 0.7
beta = (1.0 - alpha)
gamma = 0.0

masked_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, alpha, mask, beta, gamma)
```

You can change the alpha with any number in range 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried low pass filtering?

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/d6a/tutorial_js_filtering.html

With kernel 2x3 it looks better:

> cv.Mat.eye(2, 3, cv.CV_32FC1);

Then slpit your image for 3 channels and clean green and red using threshold.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-) Your answer looks like it is a good idea to *remove* the moiré. Here the user would like to create it.